# How to add/subtract rows from each other in R

Tags: r

I am trying to add and subtract rows from each other in a dataframe in R, but without adding and subtracting the row from itself. For example, if the data set is given by

```
data <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,5), y=c(3,4,8), z=c(5,6,10))
```

I am trying to add/subtract row 2 from 1, 3 from 1, and 3 from 2. I am trying to create a loop that would work for any dataset. 
I have tried `apply`, `sapply`, and `sweep` but without luck. Is there a package of methods I can use?

Thanks

Comment: `x`, `y`,  and `z` are columns.  So, subtract `y` from `x` implies subtracting columns, not rows. Do you want to subtract columns or rows?

Comment: I want to add and subtract rows not columns. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Best to give your desired outcome...

Comment: Please add your expected output to the question to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting the `x`th columns by `x-1` except when `x == 1` then it is subtracted by the last column.

```
sapply(1:ncol(data), function(x) if (x == 1) {
           data[, x] - data[, ncol(data)] 
           }  else {
           data[, x] - data[, x-1]})

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   -4    2    2
#[2,]   -4    2    2
#[3,]   -5    3    2
```

---

If you really want to subtract the rows, a similar approach can be followed.

```
t(sapply(1:nrow(data), function(x) if (x == 1) {
           data[x, ] - data[nrow(data), ] 
           }  else {
           data[x, ] - data[x-1, ]}))

#     x  y  z
#[1,] -4 -5 -5
#[2,] 1  1  1
#[3,] 3  4  4
```

Answer (score 0):

what about adding three new columns?

```
data$sub1 <- data$y - data$x
data$sub2 <- data$x - data$z
data$sub3 <- data$z - data$y

data

  x y  z sub1 sub2 sub3
1 1 3  5    2   -4    2
2 2 4  6    2   -4    2
3 5 8 10    3   -5    2
```

Comment: I did that and it works for a small dataset. But what if I have a big matrix, then this method won't be a good idea. Is there a package or loop that might work for the same idea?

Comment: uhm... I guess that loops won't be a good choice (https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/vectorized-operations.html) against vectorized operations